# Flames into cooking area

Tags: oven

Is this normal to happen [image] it doesn’t happen all the time. Just off and on when using oven

Comment: That's pretty scary

Comment: That does not seem normal. Maybe contact manufacturer?

Comment: Is it happening when you are set to certain temps? Like it doesn't happen at 325°F but does at 450°F?

Comment: I’ll have to check that out I’m not really sure . It was seo at 425 most times.

Comment: I don't think that's normal for a residential oven (though some convection setups do create gas 'poofs' occasionally, but nothing nearly like what you've shown). I'd call the manufacturer after turning it off to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Not really normal to see it happen frequently, though I have seen it happen in commercial convection ovens when they attempt to recover to a high heat. Or, simply, the oven was at 200 - 220 celsius, then the doors were opened letting out all the heat while pans were rotated, then the doors closed and the oven started to recover and heat up again while the fans were spinning up. You ended up with little 'poofs' of gas that ignited.

Throughout normal operation, however, it wasn't something you'd normally see. It worries me enough that my best advice is to discontinue use until you've been able to contact the manufacturer, or a repair place that's authorized by the manufacturer. You could have a faulty internal regulator which is something that can be pretty dangerous. It could also be a faulty part in your gas meter, which is a matter you'd need to discuss with your utility.

I'd turn it off, and get on the phone.